# "The matrix is not Hermitian or real and symmetric." in SemiDefiniteOptimization

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I wanted to run the following code with $M$ assuming to be positive definite:
[image]

However, Mathematica said that my given $M$ is not Hermitian or real and symmetric. I can change the corresponding matrix to below (which is clearly equivalent)

[image]

but changing this by hand is clearly to troubling when $M$ is large. Are there any ways to "convince" mathematica that $M$ is Hermitian or real and symmetric in Mathematica's SemidefiniteOptimization solver?

Thank you!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"(which is clearly equivalent)" It is *not* clearly equivalent, as far as I can tell you don't state anywhere that $M_{3,2}=M_{2,3}$.

If this is indeed true for you, you can automate the replacement for matrices of arbitrary size: For example

```
largeMatrix = Table[Table[Subscript[M, i, j], {i, 1, 50}], {j, 1, 50}];
largeMatrix /. {Subscript[M, i_, j_] :> 
    Subscript[M, j, i] /; i < j} // MatrixForm
```